# html textarea disabled but selectable

Tags: html, textarea

I would like to make my html textarea to appear disabled but to remain selectable. When I use "readonly", it is selectable, but appears editable. So, now we want it to appear as disabled. once I set it to "disabled", it is now not selectable.
I also tried just "throwing" text on the page, but in this case as it comes from the DB, the "newline"s are not formatted well, need the BR tag, and of course loosing the width height of the area in such a case.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't help much without sample code, but you could just use CSS to grey-out the pertinent element, then it would sort of look disabled but wouldn't be.

Comment: You can set it to readonly and then stylize the textarea?
https://jsfiddle.net/tn9jof8q/

Comment: @user3473534 thank you, exactly what I needed :) sorry, I'm just html newbie

Answer (score 0):

you can use try "readonly" as a paramater
like

```html
<textarea readonly>
      i'm read only
</textarea>
```

Comment: OP already stated that he tried setting it as `readonly`, this still makes it selectable.